# VC++ 2010 - if button1 is clicked

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a little problem with my script. I would like to check if the button1 was clicked in another event (pictureBox_Click). How could I do it?

It should works like this:

```
private: System::Void pictureBox_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

if (button1 is clicked=true)
{
  code;
  code;
  code;
}

if (button2 is clicked=true)
{
  code;
  code;
  code;
}

}
```

I will be grateful for help.

Comment: Sounds bad.  Surely this ought to be a CheckBox.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to store when the button was clicked in a variable.  Add an event handler for the button click events, and store the values.

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    buttonClicked = true;
}
private: System::Void pictureBox_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
     if (buttonClicked)
     {
         // ...
```